# Same JavaScript function returns random results

Tags: javascript

I'm confused:

```
function is_valid(name) {
    var regexp_name = /^(\d|\w)*$/gi;
    return regexp_name.test(name);
}
```

---

```
// Console
console.log(is_valid("Test"));
=> true

console.log(is_valid("Test"));
=> false

console.log(is_valid("Test"));
=> true

console.log(is_valid("Test"));
=> false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the same result as you in Firebug.

Comment: same here. surprisingly if you test it with `console.log(is_valid("!#"));` it turns out fine. and according to prolonged observations, the value returned alternates between true and false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `/g` flag.

The RegExp object is somehow reused. When the `/g` flag is present, the regex engine will start from the previous matched location until the whole string is consumed.

```
 1st call:       Test
                 ^
 after 1st call: Test   (found "Test")
                     ^
 2nd call:       Test
                     ^
 after 2nd call  Test   (found nothing, reset)
                 ^
```

BTW, `\w` is equivalent to `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` in Javascript. Therefore, the `\d|` and the `/i` flag are redundant. And since you're not using the captured group, there's no need to keep the `(…)`. This following is enough:

```
var regexp_name = /^\w*$/;
```

Comment: Ok, but why?  How about an explanation?

Comment: I'm not understanding why it isn't consuming the entire string.  The match is to the end of the string.

Comment: @George: `$` is only an assertion. It won't consume anything. An empty string at the end is a possible match. Try using `var re = /\w*/g; return re.exec(name);`. You'll see the empty string is matched in the end.

Comment: It's alternating between true to false because the regex object is reused as @KennyTM said. The `g` flag makes the `lastIndex` property (where to begin next search) jump from `0` (true - always finds a match - `"Test"`) to `4` (false - no matches from here onwards). Wrote some tests on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152452/unexpected-javascript-behaviour-issue/3152837#3152837) to confirm this behavior.